# Горизонтальное выравнивание в div у которого display:table

Tags: css, html

Здравствуйте, уважаемые специалисты, прошу помощи:
Есть блок `<div>` (`display:table`) внутри две ячейки `<div>` (`display:table-cell`) во второй ячейке находится `<div>` тоже с `display:table`, не могу выравнить ее по правому краю `text-align: right` не помогает. `float:right` работает, просто на сколько я знаю, он для этого не предназначен.

Вот мой упрощенный код: https://jsfiddle.net/m2nxgpsx/

```css
#top {display:table; width:100%;}
#top > div {display:table-cell; border:solid 1px;}
#td_enter {text-align:right;}
#enter {display:table;}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <div id="td_links">Ссылки</div>
  <div id="td_enter">
    <div id="enter">Это выравнить вправо</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте `#enter width:100%`

Comment: @DaemonHK Спасибо, а по другому нельзя? просто внутри есть еще и ячейки, а width 100% растягивает их по максимуму вот что получается: https://jsfiddle.net/m2nxgpsx/2/

Comment: @DaemonHK Мне нужны выравнить сам блок div а не его содержимое

Comment: не пойму. в ячейке `<div id="td_enter">` находится `<div id="enter">`, ему вы даете ширину 100% и при этом хотите его выровнять по правому краю? Он же всю ширину родителя занимает, что имеется в виду по выровнять?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов нет, это мне дали совет поставить width 100%, я показал что из этого получается. вот моя ситуация без width 100%: https://jsfiddle.net/m2nxgpsx/3/ спасибо за  помощь

Comment: Может. как нибудь так подойдет: https://jsfiddle.net/0qjtuqcb/

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов спасибо. проще тогда table вместо div

Comment: или вот так https://jsfiddle.net/m2nxgpsx/4/

Comment: может такой вариант подойдет https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/fq7o6mLf/

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо, хороший вариант